# Update a table using order by statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to update the table by using order by to `close_date` and `Close_time`.

My table is:

[image]

I was trying query like this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        Terminal_Id, Close_date, Close_time, SlNo,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  Close_date,Close_time) AS RN
    FROM 
        tablename
)
UPDATE cte 
SET SlNo = RN
```

Comment: what's `UPDATE cte`???

Comment: i was trying to use cte @ Rahul

Comment: Basically i want to update tablename where Close_date and Close_time will be in ascending order

Comment: Your posted query makes no sense at all.

Comment: sry,earlier i pasted wrong query.I edited it nw

Comment: So what's the question here? doesn't it work?

Comment: You're missing a comma.

Comment: From your profile I see, that you were around. Please read the link in my comment before! Voting and accpeting is the base of SO...

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be thin as this:

```
With cte As
(
SELECT SlNo,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  Close_date,Close_time) AS RN
FROM tablename
)
UPDATE cte SET SlNo=RN
```